# Using Task.Run() causes unexpected behavior in calling loop

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

I have the following C# code:

```
public List<bool> scaleActive { get; private set; }
//...
for (int i = 0; i < scaleActive.Count; i++)
{
    if (scaleActive[i])
    {
        //...
        Task.Run(() => NewportUpload.SendBasket(localTempPath,
            string.Format("{0}{1}", basketNamesBuy[i], CSV), tradeBasket,
            privateKeyFileName, privateKeyPassphrase, instinetHost, instinetUserName,
            instinetRemotePath));
        //...
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index

From debugging it, I see that the value of `i` is one greater than the size of `scaleActive` which makes no sense. Then if I just take out the `Task.Run()` and run it like this, it's fine.

```
public List<bool> scaleActive { get; private set; }
//...
for (int i = 0; i < scaleActive.Count; i++)
{
    if (scaleActive[i])
    {
        //...
        NewportUpload.SendBasket(localTempPath,
            string.Format("{0}{1}", basketNamesBuy[i], CSV), tradeBasket,
            privateKeyFileName, privateKeyPassphrase, instinetHost, instinetUserName,
            instinetRemotePath);
        //...
    }
}
```

Why would the for loop overrun the size of the `scaleActive` list? It is not being modified in any way in the function being called, or anywhere else in the program. It is initialized before the loop. The `basketNamesBuy` list is not being modified either.

Comment: What does this mean "if (scaleActive[i])"

Comment: If possible, can you make the method `async` and then try `await Task.Run()...`?

Comment: Obviously you need to capture variable inside loop scope

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin Indeed your suggestion fixes the issue by waiting for each iteration to finish, but OP is likely looking for parallel execution which means they need to start all tasks and `await Task.WhenAll(...)` rather than your sequential proposal.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yup, this makes perfectly sense. It seems it is an IO operation and if so, it it will be more efficient to perform parallel processing with `Task.WhenAll()` here.